# Adding property on each object from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a array of objects being fetched from an api and displayed on the page.

Now I want to a select dropdown for each object whose value is initially undefined, but is set to whatever value the user sets. On this user event, the object should reflect this change and it should also send an update request to the api for this new change. Here's what I have tried so far.

```
   <section class='results'>
    <p class='no-results' ng-show='!results.length && !loading'>No Results</p>

    <article class='result' ng-repeat='result in results track by $id(result)'>
      <h2><a href="{{result.docno}}">{{result.docno}}</a></h2>
      <select ng-options="grade for grade in [0,1,2]" ng-model="result.rank"></select>
      {{result.rank}}
      <!--<p></p>-->
    </article>
   </section>
```

Here results is the array and rank is the new property I want to add to each result object in results. What is the right way to update the result object each time the rank is changed?

Here is the snippet of the code in controller that populates the results array

```
$scope.loadResults = function(m) {
    results.search($scope.query, m, $scope.offset).then(function(a) {

        //Load results
        var i = 0;
        for(;i < a.hits.length; i++){
            var temp = a.hits[i];
            //temp['grade'] = undefined;
            $scope.results.push(temp);
        }

        ...
    });
};
```

I also tried to set a watch on 'result.rank' but it does not get invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming {{result.rank}} shows the correct value after a new option is selected you can use ng-change on the select to know when the model was changed due to user interaction.  You may also want to check out ng-model-options that allows you to setup a debounce/delay for triggering the change to the model when the user interacts with the control in case they quickly change their mind and you want to reduce the number of API calls.

Ex:

```
<select ng-change="updateAPI(result)"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was kinda looking for a way to set an event handler on change of each result object, that way I could make it more extensible like what I am trying to do in the future.

Comment: @adifire if you want to just watch the entire object you can use the third param to $watch for checking deep equality but if the object you have is pretty large then this can cause performance problems.  The way to do it is $scope.$watch('results', handlerFunction, true); typically I think it's better to just use the user events instead of a deep watch though since it won't slow down the digest process at all.